# how to make tableview cells expand and collapse

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have three table view cells, the due date cell should expand to 200 when selected, and 44(default) when not selected. For some reason, it will not expand.

I cannot do this in AutoLayout since it has to change, so I tried using a switch statement, and when it is on the specific index path it should expand however it failed to work.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let normalCellHeight = CGFloat(44)
    let largeCellHeight = CGFloat(200)

    switch(indexPath) {
    case [1,0]: // Due Date Cell
        return isPickerHidden ? normalCellHeight : largeCellHeight

    case [2,0]: // Notes Cell
        return largeCellHeight

    default: return normalCellHeight

    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch(indexPath) {
    case [2,0]:
        isPickerHidden = !isPickerHidden

        dueDateLabel.textColor = isPickerHidden ? .black : tableView.tintColor

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

    default: break
    }
}
```

Expected Outcome:
Due Date cell is tapped, cell expands to show the date picker

Actual Results: 
Cell is highlighted, but does not expand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reloading cell on `didSelectRow` inside `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.
Have a look at sample code below. Choose row realod animation as per your need.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
switch(indexPath) {
case [2,0]:
    isPickerHidden = !isPickerHidden

    dueDateLabel.textColor = isPickerHidden ? .black : tableView.tintColor

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates()

default: break
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload cell in didSelectRowAt delegate

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch(indexPath) {
        case [2,0]:
            isPickerHidden = !isPickerHidden

            dueDateLabel.textColor = isPickerHidden ? .black : tableView.tintColor

            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)

            default: break
        }
    }
```